# Python read timer values from link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i want extract music length from link , but this site shows music duration after complete Loaded.
i wont use chromDriver or etc. because i have many link and ChromDriver is very slow.
do you any idea for this ?
This site use "GENERIC COUNTER", can i extract values from This ?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find the tag by it's id, have you read https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thank You Simon for your answer but when i extract this tag is empty because the player in site not started to load music

Comment: Have a look at this: https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: these Driver is very slow. i want try new way

Comment: Please remember to include your current coding attempt. See [ask] and [mcve] for guidance.